# emacs only delete-trailing-whitespace while saving in programming mode

Tags: emacs, whitespace, mode

following line removes all training white space while saving.

```
(add-hook 'write-file-hooks 'delete-trailing-whitespace)
```

but I want to hook this feature only when i'm in programming mode, so i did

```
(defun nuke_traling ()
  (add-hook 'write-file-hooks 'delete-trailing-whitespace) 
)

(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'nuke_traling)
```

which doesn't is not stopping which are not in programming mode.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Making the hook variable buffer-local has been mentioned. Don't do that. Or rather, don't do it using `make-local-variable`.

The normal hook mechanisms have buffer-local support built in -- that's the purpose of the `LOCAL` argument to `add-hook`. When the hook is run, it runs *both* the global *and* the buffer-local values.

So taking the example code in the question, you could change it to use:

```el
(add-hook 'write-file-hooks 'delete-trailing-whitespace nil t)
```

And then `delete-trailing-whitespace` would be called whenever `write-file-hooks` was run, but only in the buffers in which `prog-mode-hook` had run.

However there are better ways to achieve this.

I agree with Drew that you are better to test whether your mode is derived from `prog-mode`, and with juanleon that `before-save-hook` is a better hook to use. So you might do something like:

```el
(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'my-prog-nuke-trailing-whitespace)

(defun my-prog-nuke-trailing-whitespace ()
  (when (derived-mode-p 'prog-mode)
    (delete-trailing-whitespace)))
```

But what I *actually* recommend is using either [ws-trim](https://ftp.lysator.liu.se/pub/emacs/ws-trim.el) or [ws-butler](https://github.com/lewang/ws-butler) to take care of this in a smarter way.

Blindly removing all trailing whitespace from a file is a great way to wind up committing loads of unrelated lines to a version-control repository. Both of the libraries mentioned will ensure that your own commits are free of trailing whitespace, *without* also introducing unwanted modifications elsewhere in the file.

Answer (score 8):

`write-file-hooks` is obsolete since Emacs-22, replaced by `write-file-functions`.  But this hook is a bit delicate to use (because it can also be used to *perform* the write), so I recommend you use `before-save-hook` instead.  And to make it apply only to the current buffer, just pass a non-nil value for the `local` argument of `add-hook`, as in:

```
(defun nuke_traling ()
  (add-hook 'before-save-hook #'delete-trailing-whitespace nil t))
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'nuke_traling)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because as soon as you enter a `prog-mode` mode, you add the function to `write-file-hooks`, where it remains.  And that hook applies to writing any file, regardless of the mode of its buffer.

Instead of putting that simple function on the hook, you can add a function that tests the mode and only does the whitespace deletion when it is a mode where you want to do that.

Or else you would need to make `write-file-hooks` buffer-local (which I doubt you would want want to do --- the hook is used more generally).

Comment: "Make a hook buffer-local" is an obsolete concept since Emacs-21.  All hooks have a global and a buffer-local part.  You just need to tell `add-hook` which part you want to modify.

Answer (score 1):

Bad way:

```
(add-to-list 'write-file-functions 'delete-trailing-whitespace)
```

Better way is using [ws-butler](https://github.com/lewang/ws-butler):

```
(straight-use-package 'ws-butler)
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'ws-butler-mode)
```

`ws-butler-mode` remove spaces only on changed lines.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make the variable buffer local:

```
(defun nuke_traling ()
    (make-variable-buffer-local 'write-file-hooks)
    (add-hook 'write-file-hooks 'delete-trailing-whitespace))
```

But I would recommend using `before-save-hook` instead:

```
(defun nuke_traling ()
    (add-to-list 'before-save-hook 'delete-trailing-whitespace))
```

`write-file-hooks` may be risky if used as a file-local variable, and documentation recomends using `before-save-hook` instead for thing like you want to do.

Comment: `make-variable-buffer-local` should pretty much never be called from a function.  You probably meant `make-local-variable`.  But that should not be used on hooks.  Instead you want to use the `local` argument of `add-hook`.

Answer (score -1):

In emacs 21 or later you can add this hook to a perticular mode like this:

```
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook
                (lambda () (add-to-list 'write-file-functions 'delete-trailing-whitespace)))
```